# HTML tables split cells into different number of columns for different rows not performing as expected

Tags: html, tablelayout

So I am trying to **split cells** in a table using **colspan** but I am seeing some odd behavior. In the code bellow the first table does not render as expected.

In particular the row with the 1/4 and 1/2 column are not spanning to 2x25% occupancy and then one that uses the remainder space, and this messes up the proper spanning of the 1/3 cells and 1/2 cells... On the other the second table looks as expected.

I am not sure if this is a **bug in Chrome?? it seems to have also hill behavior in IE9**, am i missing something here? Is there a better method to get this done?

You can see live version of code at: https://jsfiddle.net/4xwm33n6/

```
Unexpected alignment:
<table border="1" align="center" cellspacing="0" width="400px">
  <tr >
      <td colspan="100%"  align="center">1/1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr> 
    <td colspan="33.33%" align="center">1/3</td>
    <td colspan="33.33%" align="center">1/3</td>
    <td colspan="33.33%" align="center">1/3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr> 
    <td colspan="25%" align="center">1/4</td>
    <td colspan="25%" align="center">1/4</td>
    <td colspan="50%" align="center">1/2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr> 
    <td colspan="50%" align="center">1/2</td>
    <td colspan="50%" align="center">1/2</td>
  </tr>
</table>

This works (but two 1/4 cannot be merged as one):
<table border="1" align="center" cellspacing="0" width="400px">
  <tr >
      <td colspan="100%"  align="center">1/1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr> 
    <td colspan="33.33%" align="center">1/3</td>
    <td colspan="33.33%" align="center">1/3</td>
    <td colspan="33.33%" align="center">1/3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr> 
    <td colspan="25%" align="center">1/4</td>
    <td colspan="25%" align="center">1/4</td>
    <td colspan="25%" align="center">1/4</td>
    <td colspan="25%" align="center">1/4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr> 
    <td colspan="50%" align="center">1/2</td>
    <td colspan="50%" align="center">1/2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Fairly Certain colspan is a whole number value. It is the number of columns it is supposed to span.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do what you want to do you need something along the lines of:

```
<table>
<tr>
  <td colspan="12">1/1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td colspan="6">1/2</td>
  <td colspan="6">1/2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td colspan="4">1/3</td>
  <td colspan="4">1/3</td>
  <td colspan="4">1/3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td colspan="3">1/4</td>
  <td colspan="3">1/4</td>
  <td colspan="3">1/4</td>
  <td colspan="3">1/4</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

This way you can combine the number of cells you need.  By the way I got the 12 by using the lowest common multiple of 4 and 3...

Comment: I should have mentioned that I had tried the approach mentionned by MiltoxBeyond...  However it seem to perform worsy than using colspan as a %... You can see what I mean here:https://jsfiddle.net/bpbg4a3a/ I agree colspan is supposed to be an integer,  but apparently can also be given as %.

Comment: You have to specify a width for the table and widths for columns to get it to space evenly. But if this is all you are trying to do you may be better off with a grid layout CSS framework

Answer (score 0):

*Sorry for wrote comment like answer, I can't comment this post :(*

`colspan` mean how many cells You want to merge, not `width`. You can't set `width` in `colspan`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use colspan="#" using a number not a percent.
For example, if you want a td to go across two columns, use colspan="2"

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">4</td>
        <td>5</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xxurc50n/1/